# Prevent updates to 'modified time' when copying files to a mounted Samba folder

Tags: mount, samba, file-copy, timestamps

I don’t want the “last modified” attribute to be changed to the current date when copying files to a mounted Samba folder. How can I do this?

This behavior occurs with (K)Ubuntu 12.04 and Ubuntu 15.10. It can be reproduced using GUI browsers (tested with nautilus 3.4.2 and dolphin 2.0) and using  `cp -p` in terminal.

The Samba folder was mounted to the local file system either with:

- `sudo mount -t smbfs //mynas/folder /mnt/nas/ -o user=username`

or

- `sudo mount -t cifs //mynas/folder /home/mnt/nas/ -o user=username`.

**Notes:**

- When connecting to the same Samba folder (either with nautilus or dolphin) using a URL like `smb://username@mynas/folder/`, then I can copy files to it without having the “modified time” replaced with the current time!
- But mounting a Samba folder is more convenient, also not all tools support the smb protocol. This is why using the URI `smb://` is not a workaround for me.

Comment: Is your share mounted with the uid option set to your user? Without this, ownership and timestamp preservation wont work!

Comment: No it was not as everyone can see in the problem description. But appending the mount command to "sudo mount -t cifs //mynas/folder /home/mnt/nas/ -o user=username -o gid=1000,uid=1000" solves the problem. Many thanks for your answer :).
Wouldn't you like to  write a official answer, so I could mark it at the correct answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `cp -P` doesn't apply to your needs. You are using uppercase argument letter `-P` which is used to never follow symbolic links. 
What you want to use is lowercase to preserve timestamps: `cp -p`

> As described in the comment section of the question, using the correct gid and uid solved the problem:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //mynas/folder /home/mnt/nas/ -o user=username -o gid=1000,uid=1000
```

Comment: That's true, but still with "cp -p" the "last modified" attribute changes.

Answer (score 1):

There are several other utilities that can be used to copy files without modifying their timestamps. `rsync` (especially, using the '-t' flag) and `cpio` (using the '-m' flag) can both be used in this case. Check out the manual pages for each to see what other options might be useful.

Comment: It's not the fault of the tools I'm using to copying files that the time stamp is changed, it happens with all tools I tested. It has to be a layer below the application layer that causes this undesirable behavior.

Comment: Just tested on an smbfs mount on OSX. Using `cp -p` timestamps were not preserved when transferring to the smbfs mount. Using `rsync -avzt` timestamps were preserved correctly. So I'm leaning towards it being the tools.